# How to cause the focused text field in any app to become filled with data from Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a simple app I'm trying to write that involves storing and "pasting" snippets in to whatever text editor the user is using. I tried using event taps to simulate keyboard presses to simulate typing, but for whatever reason this isn't working. Is there a better method for getting a string to populate in the focused text field in other apps?

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate events if all text input controls usually have a `setStringValue:` method?

Comment: Because I'm trying to do it in apps running on the same system, not my app. For example I want the app I'm writing to be able to paste a snippet in to Xcode by pressing a keyboard shortcut my app is listening for.

Comment: what about writing to the pasteboard then?

Comment: The app already writes to the pasteboard, I wanted to automate the pasting using keyboard shortcuts.